# underbound belongs to ideal of lattice

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $(L,\leq)$ be a complete lattice and suppose $A$ is an ideal of $L$ (i.e. for all $i \in I$ and $a \in L$, one has that $a \wedge i \in I$). Suppose $c \in L$ is such that $c \leq \bigvee A'$, where $A' \subseteq A$ is a finite subset of $A$. How does one show that $c \in A$? If one has that $\bigvee A' \in A$, then this is of course obvious, but I am not sure if this holds or not.

Comment: The claim of your second sentence is true if the word "ideal" is taken to mean "lattice ideal", but it is false if the word "ideal" is taken to mean "order ideal". The definition of "ideal" in your first sentence is that of "order ideal", so your claim is false as written. For a counterexample, let $L$ be any lattice with incomparable elements $a$ and $b$, and let $A$ be the set of elements $x$ such that  $x\leq a$ or $x\leq b$.

Comment: (continued). If you change the definition of ideal to "lattice ideal", then your statement is true. A subset $I\subseteq L$ is a lattice ideal if it is closed under finite joins and also closed downwards. ((i) $a, b\in I$ implies $a\vee b\in I$, and (ii) $a\in I$ and $b\leq a$ implies $b\in I$.)